# Convert string to name of object (casting)

Tags: javascript, string, object, casting

I want to cast a string to an existing object. 
Background: I am using only JS, no libraries and no server side code. I have existing objects with elements I wish to display. I pass the name of the object using a query string so it arrives as a string. Example `?Room=Cube` and what I wind up with is

```
nextRoom = getQueryString();  // which returns a string
```

and I want to display the Cube object. However nextRoom contains "Cube" and JS is not helpful, if I call a display function:

```
display(nextRoom)
```

Javascript treats it as a string and fails. Currently I fake it out with the object:

```
castToObj{"Cube":Cube, "Other":Other, "Etc":Etc, ........}
  .....  
room = castToObj[nextRoom];    // accessing the object returns the room Object
```

then I can display the room by calling:

```
display(room);  // now JS treats the parameter as an object
```

But this requires me to rewrite code to modify the `castToObj{}` contents every time I add a room. I would like a way to turn "Cube" into Cube, in other words turn a string into an object. I have tried many variations but have been unsuccessful. I could list ways I have tried but that seems senseless because they were all failures.
HELP! PLEASE!

P.S I retired about twenty years ago before learning C++, OOP, etcetera so my javascript skills are just my "C" programming experience expanded.

Comment: Is "Cube" object stored anywhere and you want to retrieve it by its name?

Comment: Can you please explain how Cube etc are defined?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `JSON.parse()`, but you didn't really explain what `getQueryString()` returns, or what `display()` expects.

Comment: Sorry I did not tag you with the @xxxx to receive updates. The solution was provided, below, by user3703422.  Thank you all for your help. Msanderz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an empty container object:

```
myElements = {};
```

Then change your code wherever you define an element, from

```
Cube =  ... whatever ...
```

to

```
myElements.Cube = ... whatever ....
```

for all of your elements (Other, Etc ...).

After this, you simply use

```
nextRoom = getQueryString(); 
display(myElements[nextRoom]);
```

Comment: Fantastic! I tried it on my simple test program using console.log to test for passing an object and it worked perfectly! I see now that it is just a more elegant version of my kluge castToObj{}. I remember reading somewhere that the [name] can be either a string or element, this is too late for my current version but will be great for future coding.  Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you, @msanderz. Yes, this is basically the same as your solution, with a different syntax.

Please accept my answer (click checkmark for accept)!

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script eval function but depending on the situation it might open your program to XSS attack. You should use it carefully.